# Python kivy Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, kivy

This is well known and quite common issue. I've tried all found solutions but no success. I'm trying to make simple python app using kivy. After running below code I'm getting bunch of errors. Code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

After running the code:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Patryk\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-01-18_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Could not initialize EGL'
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 968, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 272, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 209, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 66, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

PATH and PYTHONPATHS contains:

```
C:\Windows\System32;
C:\Python;
C:\Python\DLLs; 
C:\Python\Lib;
C:\Python\Scripts;
C:\Python\share\sdl2;
C:\Python\share\glew
```

Before I've started to investigate I saw this:

[POP Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moxyy.jpg)

I've tried few interpreters. Python 3.5.2, 3.6.1 and 3.7.2. The error is the same. Any ideas?

---

List of installed libs:

```
Kivy    1.10.1  1.10.1
Kivy-Garden 0.1.4   
Kivy-examples   1.10.1  1.10.1
Pygments    2.3.1   2.3.1
certifi 2018.11.29  2018.11.29
chardet 3.0.4   3.0.4
docutils    0.14    0.14
idna    2.8 2.8
kivy.deps.angle 0.1.7   0.1.7
kivy.deps.glew  0.1.10  0.1.10
kivy.deps.gstreamer 0.1.13  0.1.13
kivy.deps.sdl2  0.1.18  0.1.18
pip 18.1    18.1
pypiwin32   223 223
python-firebase 1.2 1.2
pywin32 224 224
requests    2.21.0  2.21.0
setuptools  40.6.3  40.6.3
urllib3 1.24.1  1.24.1
wheel   0.32.3  0.32.3
```

Comment: This is essentially a generic 'your Kivy doesn't have all the compiled components it needs' error. How did you install it?

Comment: Step by step as instructions on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: Do you definitely have kivy.deps.sdl2 installed?

Comment: Yes. You will find the list below.